# How to avoid ServiceChannel leak when caching ServiceChannelFactory?

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

Currently I cache the `ServiceChannelFactory` and create a new `ServiceChannel` every time I need one. I expected the `ServiceChannels` to be disposed by the garbage collector. However, the factory keeps a reference to each channel, so that it can close the channel when you call `ServiceFactoryChannel.Close()`. This results in many old channels being alive up to the point that everything stops working.

How can I cache the factory and still let the garbage collector dispose of my channels?

My code looks like this:

```
public class ServiceChannel
{
    // Returns a ServiceChannel
    public static TService Get<TService>()
    {
        var factory = GetChannelFactory<TService>();
        string url = GetEndpoint<TService>();
        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
        return factory.CreateChannel(endPoint);
    }

    // Returns a ServiceChannelFactory, preferably from the cache
    public static ChannelFactory<TService> GetChannelFactory<TService>()
    {
        var cacheKey = string.Format("MyProduct.Library.ServiceChannel.GetChannelFactory<{0}>()", typeof(TService));
        var cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
        var factory = cache[cacheKey] as ChannelFactory<TService>;
        if (factory == null)
        {
            factory = GetChannelFactoryUncached<TService>();
            cache.Insert(cacheKey, factory);
        }
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *everything stops working*? You should share by what means you are caching (*code is helpful*), e.g. are you using sliding expiration, in-memory cache, etc.

Comment: I keep creating channels. Every channel keeps a outgoing port open, so after a while these are all used up. The result is that the server can  no longer make new TCP connections.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IoC container like Autofac/Unity/Ninject, or for a very basic but fast one use DynamoIOC.

When setting up your container, have a single reference to ServiceChannelFactory. When you create an IServiceChannel (to your service IMyService), register it as well.

But be careful, when your IServiceChannel.Faulted event is hit, you will need to close, dispose and recreate it, adding it back into the IoC container. This way, whenever a caller requires access to your service, it will be in a non-faulted state.